# Wrapping a script with subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, scripting

I have a script that's provided with another software package - which I would not like to modify in any way. I need to execute this script, provide a password, and then interact with it from the terminal (using raw_input, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

[pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) is what you want to use.

> Pexpect is a Python module for
>   spawning child applications and
>   controlling them automatically.
>   Pexpect can be used for automating
>   interactive applications such as ssh,
>   ftp, passwd, telnet, etc. It can be
>   used to a automate setup scripts for
>   duplicating software package
>   installations on different servers. It
>   can be used for automated software
>   testing. It should work on any
>   platform that supports the standard
>   Python pty module. The Pexpect
>   interface focuses on ease of use so
>   that simple tasks are easy.